# New property with method of this same object?

Tags: javascript, object

It is possible to create new property with method of this same object? Below is the code where I tried to do it without the expected result.

```js
var base = {
  set: function(pr, v) {
    this.pr = v;
  }
}

base.set("cat", "Filemon")
console.log(base)
```

Comment: What *did* you expect?

Comment: Use `this[pr] = v;`, not `this.pr`

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem :)